# date time picker not returning hour and minute

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have created one datetime picker, its not returning the hour and minute, returns only the date, i need to return datetime along with hour and minute, here is my code.

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return ((DateTime)value).ToString(parameter as string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return null;
        }
        try
        {
           DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value as string, parameter as string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return dt as DateTime?;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my wpf page.

```
<toolkit:DataField>
    <controls:DatePicker Width="190"  x:Name="DatePickerRequestedDelivery" Text="{Binding endDate, Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}, ConverterParameter=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}" MaxHeight="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >

    </controls:DatePicker>
</toolkit:DataField>
```

Can any one help me to converter to return datetime with time like below  please

2014-12-01 10:33

Thanks

Comment: What value has parameter 'parameter '? Debug and see this value

Comment: value in parameter is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Comment: and in the parameter 'value' you pass the hours?

Comment: i pass the date and time

Comment: I use both functions and work for me, which of the two doesn't return the hours? Maybe your problem is somewhere else, not in control. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringFormat="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt"

If you dont want AM/PM.. ignore tt..

Comment: in the same format we are passing in the parameter field. still i am getting only the date